# how can i solve This Issue with store procedure and queryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

i have Multiple Datalist in the same page .. the user can click on records and this will redirect him to view page to view the infos. . I used querystring to send ID For the Clicked Record to view Page ... The problem is when i select record with ID EX: 17 .. Sometimes the info is correct but not always because if there is other record in other Table with ID ex:17 It replace it Instead Of the Clicked One !

Im Using c# / Asp.net 4.0 framework / sql server 2008

Here is my Code

StartPage.aspx ( The DataLists Page ) :

```
public partial class MainMasterStartPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected SqlConnection _connection;
    protected SqlCommand _command;
    protected SqlDataAdapter _adp;
    protected System.Data.DataTable _tbl;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(this.IsPostBack))
        {
            // For News DataList
            prepareConnection();
            _command.CommandText = "select top 5 * from News ORDER BY id DESC";
            _adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
            _tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
            _adp.SelectCommand = _command;
            _adp.Fill(_tbl);

            dlNews.DataSource = _tbl;
            dlNews.DataBind();


            // For Sports DataList
            prepareConnection();
            _command.CommandText = "select top 5 * from Sports ORDER BY id DESC";
            _adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
            _tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
            _adp.SelectCommand = _command;
            _adp.Fill(_tbl);

            dlSports.DataSource = _tbl;
            dlSports.DataBind();



            // For Technology DataList
            prepareConnection();
            _command.CommandText = "select top 5 * from Technology ORDER BY id DESC";
            _adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
            _tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
            _adp.SelectCommand = _command;
            _adp.Fill(_tbl);

            dlTechnology.DataSource = _tbl;
            dlTechnology.DataBind();



            // For Articles DataList
            prepareConnection();
            _command.CommandText = "select top 5 * from Articles ORDER BY id DESC";
            _adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
            _tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
            _adp.SelectCommand = _command;
            _adp.Fill(_tbl);

            dlArticles.DataSource = _tbl;
            dlArticles.DataBind();



            // For Islamics DataList
            prepareConnection();
            _command.CommandText = "select top 5 * from Islamics ORDER BY id DESC";
            _adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
            _tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
            _adp.SelectCommand = _command;
            _adp.Fill(_tbl);

            dlIslamics.DataSource = _tbl;
            dlIslamics.DataBind();



        }

    }


    protected void prepareConnection()
    {
        _connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SONIC-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BrainStorms;User ID=sa;Password=gg123");
        _connection.Open();
        _command = new SqlCommand();
        _command.Connection = _connection;

    }
```

and The Viewpage to display the record that is already been clicked :

```
public partial class View : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected SqlCommand News_command;
    protected SqlCommand Sports_command;
    protected SqlCommand Technology_command;
    protected SqlCommand Articles_command;
    protected SqlCommand Islamics_command;

    protected SqlDataAdapter News_adp;
    protected SqlDataAdapter Sports_adp;
    protected SqlDataAdapter Technology_adp;
    protected SqlDataAdapter Articles_adp;
    protected SqlDataAdapter Islamics_adp;

    protected System.Data.DataTable News_tbl;
    protected System.Data.DataTable Sports_tbl;
    protected System.Data.DataTable Technology_tbl;
    protected System.Data.DataTable Articles_tbl;
    protected System.Data.DataTable Islamics_tbl;

    protected SqlConnection _connection;
    protected string _ID;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Request.QueryString["ID"] != null))
        {
            _ID = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
        }

        //for The News dataList
        prepareConnection();

        News_command.CommandText = "select * from News where ID=@ID";
        News_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", _ID);
        News_adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        News_tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
        News_adp.SelectCommand = News_command;
        News_adp.Fill(News_tbl);


        if (News_tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lblID.Text = News_tbl.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
            lblTitle.Text = News_tbl.Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();
            lblContent.Text = News_tbl.Rows[0]["Contect"].ToString();

        }


        //For The Sports DataList
        prepareConnection();

        Sports_command.CommandText = "select * from Sports where ID=@ID";
        Sports_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", _ID);
        Sports_adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        Sports_tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
        Sports_adp.SelectCommand = Sports_command;
        Sports_adp.Fill(Sports_tbl);


        if (Sports_tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lblID.Text = Sports_tbl.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
            lblTitle.Text = Sports_tbl.Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();
            lblContent.Text = Sports_tbl.Rows[0]["Contect"].ToString();
        }



        //for The Technology DataList
        prepareConnection();

        Technology_command.CommandText = "select * from Technology where ID=@ID";
        Technology_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", _ID);
        Technology_adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        Technology_tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
        Technology_adp.SelectCommand = Technology_command;
        Technology_adp.Fill(Technology_tbl);


        if (Technology_tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lblID.Text = Technology_tbl.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
            lblTitle.Text = Technology_tbl.Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();
            lblContent.Text = Technology_tbl.Rows[0]["Contect"].ToString();
        }


        //For The Articles DataList
        prepareConnection();

        Articles_command.CommandText = "select * from Articles where ID=@ID";
        Articles_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", _ID);
        Articles_adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        Articles_tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
        Articles_adp.SelectCommand = Articles_command;
        Articles_adp.Fill(Articles_tbl);


        if (Articles_tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lblID.Text = Articles_tbl.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
            lblTitle.Text = Articles_tbl.Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();
            lblContent.Text = Articles_tbl.Rows[0]["Contect"].ToString();
        }


        //For The Islamics DataList
        prepareConnection();

        Islamics_command.CommandText = "select * from Islamics where ID=@ID";
        Islamics_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", _ID);
        Islamics_adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        Islamics_tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
        Islamics_adp.SelectCommand = Islamics_command;
        Islamics_adp.Fill(Islamics_tbl);


        if (Islamics_tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lblID.Text = Islamics_tbl.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
            lblTitle.Text = Islamics_tbl.Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();
            lblContent.Text = Islamics_tbl.Rows[0]["Contect"].ToString();
        }



    }

    protected void prepareConnection()
    {
        _connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SONIC-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BrainStorms;User ID=sa;Password=gg123");
        _connection.Open();
        News_command = new SqlCommand();
        News_command.Connection = _connection;
        Sports_command = new SqlCommand();
        Sports_command.Connection = _connection;
        Technology_command = new SqlCommand();
        Technology_command.Connection = _connection;
        Articles_command = new SqlCommand();
        Articles_command.Connection = _connection;
        Islamics_command = new SqlCommand();
        Islamics_command.Connection = _connection;

    }

}
```

and Here Is The StartPage.aspx Source :

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="MainMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeFile="StartPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MainMasterStartPage" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
        <div class="MainLatest">
            <div id="mainNews" style="clear: both; text-decoration: none; color: Black; text-align: right;
                direction: rtl; width: auto; height: auto; margin-right: 0px; float: right; margin-top: 5px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #7F2423;">
                <div id="news" style="border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 15px;background-color: #EAE9E4;">
                    <h3 style="background-color: #35496A; color: white; text-align: center; width: 650px;
                        float: right; border-bottom: 4px solid #7F2423; margin-bottom: 8px; padding-right: 5px;">
                        آخر الأخبار</h3>
                    <asp:DataList ID="dlNews" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a href='./NewsView.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("ID") %>' style="text-decoration: none;">
                                <div id="123">
                                    <div id="image" style="clear: both; float: right; margin: 0 5px 10px 10px;">
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/epica.jpg" Style="height: 70px;
                                            width: 130px; border: 1px solid black;" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="title" style="position: relative; float: right; top: -14px; right: 0px;
                                        height: 69px;">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title") %>' Style="font-size: 15px;
                                            font-weight: bold; line-height: 110px; "></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
                </div>
                <div id="sports" style="border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 15px;background-color: #EAE9E4;">
                    <h3 style="background-color: #03C0F8; text-align: center; color: white; width: 650px;
                        float: right; border-bottom: 4px solid #7F2423; margin-bottom: 8px; padding-right: 5px;">
                        الرياضة</h3>
                    <asp:DataList ID="dlSports" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a href='./SportsView.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("ID") %>' style="text-decoration: none;">
                                <div id="123">
                                    <div id="image" style="clear: both; float: right; margin: 0 5px 10px 10px;">
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/epica.jpg" Style="height: 70px;
                                            width: 130px; border: 1px solid black;" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="title" style="position: relative; float: right; top: -18px; right: -2px;
                                        height: 76px;">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title") %>' Style="font-size: 15px;
                                            font-weight: bold; line-height: 110px;"></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
                </div>
                <div id="technology"style="border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 15px;background-color: #EAE9E4;">
                    <h3 style="background-color: #FF9900; text-align: center; color: #7F2423; width: 650px;
                        float: right; border-bottom: 4px solid #7F2423; margin-bottom: 8px; padding-right: 5px;">
                        أخبار التكنولوجيا</h3>
                    <asp:DataList ID="dlTechnology" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a href='./TechnologyView.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("ID") %>' style="text-decoration: none;">
                                <div id="123">
                                    <div id="image" style="clear: both; float: right; margin: 0 5px 10px 10px;">
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/epica.jpg" Style="height: 70px;
                                            width: 130px; border: 1px solid black;" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="title" style="position: relative; float: right; top: -18px; right: -2px;
                                        height: 76px;">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title") %>' Style="font-size: 15px;
                                            font-weight: bold; line-height: 110px;"></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
                </div>
                <div id="articles"style="border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 15px;background-color: #EAE9E4;">
                    <h3 style="background-color: #7F2423; text-align: center; color: white; width: 650px;
                        float: right; border-bottom: 4px solid #7F2423; margin-bottom: 8px; padding-right: 5px;">
                        مقالات</h3>
                    <asp:DataList ID="dlArticles" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a href='./ArticlesView.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("ID") %>' style="text-decoration: none;">
                                <div id="123">
                                    <div id="image" style="clear: both; float: right; margin: 0 5px 10px 10px;">
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/epica.jpg" Style="height: 70px;
                                            width: 130px; border: 1px solid black;" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="title" style="position: relative; float: right; top: -18px; right: -2px;
                                        height: 76px;">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title") %>' Style="font-size: 15px;
                                            font-weight: bold; line-height: 110px;"></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
                </div>
                <div id="islamics"style="border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 15px;background-color: #EAE9E4;">
                    <h3 style="background-color: #FF9900; text-align: center; color: #7F2423; width: 650px;
                        float: right; border-bottom: 4px solid #7F2423; margin-bottom: 8px; padding-right: 5px;">
                        إسلاميات</h3>
                    <asp:DataList ID="dlIslamics" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a href='./IslamicsView.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("ID") %>' style="text-decoration: none;">
                                <div id="123">
                                    <div id="image" style="clear: both; float: right; margin: 0 5px 10px 10px;">
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/epica.jpg" Style="height: 70px;
                                            width: 130px; border: 1px solid black;" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="title" style="position: relative; float: right; top: -18px; right: -2px;
                                        height: 76px;">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title") %>' Style="font-size: 15px;
                                            font-weight: bold; line-height: 110px;"></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

and Here is The ViewPage.aspx Source:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <p dir="rtl">
       <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>
    &quot;</p>
<p dir="rtl">
   (<asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>
    )</p>
<p dir="rtl">
  :</p>
<p dir="rtl">
    <asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>
</p>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no uniqueness in your ID, that's always going to be problematic. The best thing I can suggest is that you pass some more arguments that will help uniquely define the table row you really want to display.

More fundamentally, I'd ask whether you should change your database so that your ID column is unique to avoid hacks like adding unnecessary complexity to your queryString.

P.S. I would have rather added this as a comment, but I think I'm too new (reputation too low) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You should only pull the record from the table which contains the `ID`.

You should be able to do this by providing the *Topic* (News, Sports, Tech, etc..)  in the query string of your `HyperLink`s.

Use this on your `View` page to choose the appropriate table to query.  Don't query all of them, query the *right* one.